# In Screen Sharing, how do I stop the local Mac from grabbing Mission Control keyboard shortcuts meant for the remote Mac?

Tags: keyboard, mission-control, screen-sharing

I have two Macs, each with `^-1` through `^-4` configured to switch between Mission Control desktops in Keyboard/Shortcuts. When I use Screen Sharing, these shortcuts always go to the local Mac, never to the remote Mac, regardless of whether the remote Mac otherwise has focus.

If I go into Keyboard/Shortcuts and disable these on the local Mac, I can then use them on the remote Mac. However, it's a hassle to toggle these every time I start/stop using Screen Sharing. Is there a way to get the local Mac to stop grabbing the shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

I have my local machine set to use Option for Mission Control.  I set the remote Macs to use Control.  This way, I have entirely separate key combinations.

Comment: I may have to settle for something like that, but it's annoying enough getting my fingers to learn to switch back and forth between my MacBook's keyboard and the PC keyboard I have plugged into my iMac.

Answer (score 0):

I use Better Touch Tool for this. I.e.:

- On the remote machine I assign *^+Number,* *^+Left* and *^+Right* to select a Mission Control screen.
- On the local Mac I assign *^+Space+Number*, *^+Space+Left* and *^+Space+Right* to the same functions.
- On the local computer I assign *^+...* to *^+Space+...* inside Better Touch Tool **to all Apps**. Additionally I assign ^+... to the same keys ^+... inside Better Touch Tool **only to the Screen Sharing app**.

**Attention:** When assigning the keys inside Better Touch Tool **to the Screen Sharing app** you must pay attention that the *Non Recursive* box is checked to avoid sending the same keys in a loop.